# Action<T> delegate vs. event handler related to dispose

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates, compact-framework

I am looking for architectural advice as well as deeper understanding of delegates and lambdas (in addition to needing to fix a real problem!)

We have code interacting with a device (a scale) via the serial port on a pda. We wire up a view to receive data from the device. Since only one view at a time is "connecting" to our scale instance, we have used a property of type Action to handle the interaction between the scale instance and the view (instead of subscribing to an event). The view then sets that property to a lambda that takes the value from the scale and modifies the UI.

The problem we are currently having is on Dispose of our view. If the scale is currently sending data (and we are inside the Action handler) when the view is closed by the user (at which time we force a Dispose as we are using the CF) the app hangs: the Action lambda never finishes running AND the Dispose of the scale instance hangs when trying to close the SerialPort.

1. Is there a key difference in how Action is a property on a class is handled in a situation like this compared with an event?
2. Based on log details, the code is inside the Action lambda (which modifies some UI elements) when Dispose is called on the view. These are both on the UI thread -- how can they both be running at the same time? Did I not get enough sleep last night?
3. Does anyone see some poor architectural decisions here that should be corrected?

Thank you. I can try to get some code samples in here if the description doesn't make enough sense.

Comment: 2 sounds like *maybe* re-entrancy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When not used as expression tree, a lambda is converted to a normal delegate, so that shouldn't be the problem.

But the whole thing sounds like a deadlock/concurrency issue. Instead of closing the serial port directly, use a signal for the duration of the action handler (which likely is concurrently running in a different thread - check that again), so that you can gracefully wait for it to terminate before closing the port.

Comment: As noted in Reed Copsey's comments to his answer, the DataReceived event IS raised on a secondary thread. We added the signal as Lucero suggested and the problem *seems* to be resolved.

Comment: Steve, thanks for the followup. Glad the suggestion worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

1. No - an event is really just a delegate, just like Action
2. They can't be running on the same time in the same thread - It's more likely that you're Disposing in a separate thread, or the action handler is running in a separate thread.  If this is happening in response to the serial port, realize that serial port events happen on background threads.
3. There really isn't enough information here to tell what should or shouldn't be changed from an architectural standpoint.  That being said, I question why you're not using events - There really is no advantage to using "action" vs. using an event handler, but the latter sounds like it fits the mental model more clearly, and would show your intent more clearly.

Comment: 2. I was thinking the port events were happening on a background thread, but I don't have to call Invoke to update the UI so I thought I must be wrong. Now I'm confused as to why I wouldn't need Invoke.

3. Laziness and not seeing a benefit for an event when Action<T> is so easy to use.

Comment: @Steve: You mentioned you're on CF - depending on the platform, UI updates from a bg thread don't *always* cause exceptions, especially on CF.  However, they're still not a supported operation, so you should still use invoke.  As for the threading - see SerialPort.DataReceived: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived.aspx   "The DataReceived event is raised on a secondary thread when data is received from the SerialPort object"